# div structure with 3 columns

Tags: html, css

I'm beginner of HTML and CSS. During my challenge, I want to show 3 columns div with 6 items.
I'm attaching refer image on this.

[image: This is visualization what I want]

I'm trying to make that on this https://liveweave.com/k1QrYO but I couldn't make it.

Could you guys please help me?

```css
.lw { font-size: 60px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

<p class="lw">Hello Weaver!</p>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you wish to use bootstrap or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [css flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.item {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 2px;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100vw - 16px);
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  justify-content: strech;
}

.main-container div.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-container div.first-container {
  flex: 2; /* because in the picture you posted the first box was a bit larger */
}

.main-container div.container div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-container'>
  <div class='container first-container'>
    <div class='item first'>
      First
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container second-container'>
    <div class='item second'>Second</div>
    <div class='item third'>Third</div>
  </div>
  <div class='container third-container'>
    <div class='item fourth'>Fourth</div>
    <div class='item fifth'>Fifth</div>
    <div class='item sixth'>Sixth</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [CSS Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) for main 3 columns and [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to inner column.

I have also used `CSS Grid` in `.card` to  center the text in it vertically and horizontally with `place-items: center` property.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 25% 25%;
  gap: 1rem;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 800px;
}

.card {
  background: #4472C4;
  color: #fff;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid > * {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 400px;
  gap: 0.6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
    1st
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="card">2nd</div>
    <div class="card">3rd</div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="card">4th</div>
    <div class="card">5th</div>
    <div class="card">6th</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS grid job

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:2fr 1fr 1fr; /* control the width of columns here */
  grid-auto-rows:50px; /* control the height here */
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
  grid-gap:5px;
}

.container * {
  grid-row:span 2;
  background:red;
}

.container :first-child {
  grid-row:span 6;
}

.container :nth-child(2),
.container :nth-child(3) {
  grid-row:span 3;
  grid-column:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is surely possible. I recommend the usage of classes for this purpose to avoid implementing the same elements too many times.

```css
.h33 {
    height: 33%;
}

.h50 {
    height: 50%;
}

.h100 {
    height: 100%;
}

.w33 {
    width: 33%;
}

.w50 {
    width: 50%;
}

.w100 {
    width: 100%;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

<p class="lw">Hello Weaver!</p>

<div class="flex" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    <div class="w33 h100">
        <div class="w100 h100" style="background-color: red;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w33 h100">
        <div class="w100 h50" style="background-color: red;">
        </div>
        <div class="w100 h50" style="background-color: green;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 300px;">
        <div class="w100 h33" style="background-color: red;">
        </div>
        <div class="w100 h33" style="background-color: green;">
        </div>
        <div class="w100 h33" style="background-color: blue;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```